# I have a code in index.js file in android project using eclipse adt,

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

**Now where do i see console.log [text] printed when i run the project using emulator?**

```
function getData(id){

    // Dummy Data to be replaced with data from the server
    console.log('get data for partner '+id);
    var sendData = {
        hotel_id : id,
        user_id : userID
    };
    console.log(sendData);

    var postData = JSON.stringify(sendData);

    timeoutPost(5000,URL,{'postData':postData},function(returnData){
        console.log('received data for hotel id '+id);
        if(returnData.loginStatus){
            if(returnData.status){
                menuData = returnData.data;
                setupAppForPartner();
            }else{
                popupMsg(SERVER_ISSUE_MSG);
            }
        }else{
            goLogin();
        }
    }
}

function setupAppForPartner(){

console.log('setup the app partner pages');  

cleanPage();

initData();

    createHeader();
    console.log('Debug print 1');
    createTopNav();
    console.log('Debug print 2');
    createMenupage();
    createpre();
    console.log('Debug print 3');
    createHeaderMenuPopup();
    console.log('Debug print 4');
    createCat();
    console.log('Debug print 6');


    $.mobile.loadPage("#pagePartnerStory");
    $.mobile.changePage("#pagePartnerStory");
    console.log('Debug print 14');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console messages are printed in Logcat in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

We need to check it in the log cat in eclipse,after running the app,we will have text printed by console.log over there.Since it was displaying a lot i was not able to check it, we can use search option over there to search for a particular text